# Javascript - avoid duplicated questions into an array

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, chancejs

I have this snippet in my class that use chance.js to generate a random number:

```js
this.askQuestions = [];        
this.questions = JSON.parse(this.questionsData);
for(let i = 0; i < 10; i++){
   let n = chance.integer({min: 0, max: this.questions.length - 1});
   this.askQuestions.push({
       questionIndex: n,
       question: this.questions[n].question,
       choices: this.questions[n].possibleAnswers
   });
}
```

I'm using it to extract random questions from a json file that have 2000+ entries. During the debug I've set the fixed number of `10` iterations bur I'm working to let the user set a number between 1 and 100. I've noticed that sometimes I will have some questions duplicated and I don't want that this can occur. Can anyone suggest me a way to check and eventually replace duplicated entries into the questions array?

Comment: Looks like you're looking for https://chancejs.com/miscellaneous/unique.html

Comment: I've already saw it but the `chance.unique` function returns an array and I need a single number at a time :)

Comment: nope, you don't... instead of looping from 0 to N, generate N unique numbers and loop over these.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `unique()` method on `chance` object to get unique integers.

```
 this.askQuestions = [];
    
    this.questions = JSON.parse(this.questionsData);
    const questionNumbers = chance.unique(chance.integer, 100, {min: 0, max: this.questions.length - 1})

    for(let i = 0; i < 10; i++){
        let n = questionNumbers[i];

        this.askQuestions.push({
            questionIndex: n,
            question: this.questions[n].question,
            choices: this.questions[n].possibleAnswers
        });
    }
```

Comment: I will test this solution and let you know.

Comment: Yes. If you ask me, there's no reason to use a library for such a simple task.

Answer (score 1):

One of the ways to solve your problem without using any libraries would be to make an array of possible values and remove elements when they are randomly selected:

```js
const N = this.questions.map((_, i) => i);

for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    const n = Math.floor(Math.round() * N.length);
    N.splice(n, 1); // remove N[n]

    this.askQuestions.push({
        questionIndex: n,
        question: this.questions[n].question,
        choices: this.questions[n].possibleAnswers
    });
}
```

Comment: This is an interesting solution, it will give me tha ability to remove chance.js from the script dependencies but at the moment by using this way I will need to refactor all the code because I'm using chance also in other parts of the code